# Using AWS Access Key on AWX

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying to install docker using [this playbook](https://github.com/do-community/ansible-playbooks) on an AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu) using AWX. Under credentials, I am specifying the AWS Access Key and Secret as shown below:

[image]

I have created an IAM user as well:
[image]

After configuring Project, Inventory, credentials and template on AWX, I get the error below when I run the job. I have no idea why AWX is defaulting to use ssh with user root instead of the credentials configured. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: In your inventory, what is the value of `ansible_user`? And your question is super confusing talking about AWS credentials and then abruptly switching to SSH usernames -- they have absolutely zero to do with one another

Comment: I csnt seem to find the value of `ansible_user`...where do i look? (am new to ansible haha)
To your point @mdaniel, I also dont get it why ansible displays that ssh related error yet I did not setup ssh anywhere on awx. What I want used is the aws IAM user credentails instead. I dont know if I make any sense

Comment: If you're new to ansible, then starting with AWX is going to be uphill, since it only automates playbooks and isn't a wizard. Stop and read some tutorials.